# Отображение данных модели ForeignKey в админке

Tags: python, django

Модель

```
class saloon(...)
   ...
   saloon_name = models.CharField(...)
   ...
```

и 2ая

```
class saloon_like(...)
    ...
    saloon_likes = models.ForeignKey(saloon)
    ...
```

для отображения в админке не 'saloon_object' , а название, в моделе я пишу:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self. ***А ЧТО ЗДЕСЬ?***
```

`self.saloon_likes__saloon_name`  не подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.saloon_likes.saloon_name
```

Если отношения один_к_одному или многие_к_одному, то поднимаемся вверх с помощью точечной нотации. Текущее поле, которое указано в качестве связующего будет представлять "верхнюю" модель.

Если же надо один_ко_многим то:

```
saloon = Saloon()
saloon_like = Saloon_like(saloon_likes=saloon)
saloon_like2 = Saloon_like(saloon_likes=saloon)
all_likes = saloon.saloon_like_set.all()
```